# $S:=\{A \in M(3,\mathbb R) : A^TA(e_1)=e_1 ; A^TA(e_2)=A^TA(e_3)=0\}$ ; then does $S$ contain a nilpotent matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-rank, nilpotence

$S:=\{A \in M(3,\mathbb R) : A^TA(e_1)=e_1 ; A^TA(e_2)=A^TA(e_3)=0\}$ , where $e_1,e_2,e_3$ are the standard vectors of $\mathbb R^3$ . Then is it true that $S$ contains a nilpotent matrix ? Does $S$ contain a matrix of rank $1$ ?

Comment: It would improve your post to show what efforts you've made to solve the problem before posting.  In one respect you will convey to Readers whether you understand what the problem is asking or if the difficulty lies in your misunderstanding the notation used to define $S$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider mapping $e_1$ to $e_2$ and doing something trivial with the other two basis vectors. This answers both parts if you squint long enough and think about the definition for a rank $1$ matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $A$ were nilpotent, say $A^n=0$. Then we should have $(A^T)^nA^ne_1=0$.

The projection onto $e_1\Bbb R$ clearly is of rank $1$ and $\in S$.

Comment: I don't see how the first line is helpful at all. It is obviously true based on the assumption, but it doesn't really lead to an answer.

Comment: It is tempting to think that $A^TAe_1 = e_1$ would rule out $A$ being nilpotent.  But Cameron's Answer (terse though it is) shows this cannot be ruled out.

Comment: @hardmath I was trying not to give it away fully because OP didn't put any effort into the post. I'm more generous with users who show plenty of good faith.